# How can I switch a model's datasource in loopback more than once? attachTo is not working

Tags: javascript, loopbackjs, loopback, angular-loopback, v4l2loopback

I have a model that I need to switch ***dataSources*** whenever I want. For that, I created a remote method on that model and used the ***attachTo()*** method.

```
// myModel.js

 switchDataSource = function(req, fn){
 const app = MyModel.app;
 console.log('req.dataSource ', req.dataSource);

 if(req.dataSource === 'datasource1'){
  MyModel.attachTo(app.dataSources.datasource1);
 } else if(req.dataSource === 'datasource2'){
  MyModel.attachTo(app.dataSources.pagarmeTest);
 } 
 console.log('Datasource Attached: ', MyModel.getDataSource().settings.name);
 fn();
}
```

The first time I call the remote method the datasource is changed accordingly.

For example, `datasource1` is attached to `myModel`, and now I call the remote method with `datasource2`. This will work just fine.

However, if I call this remote method, passing `datasource1` - the one that was previously attached to `myModel` - it wont work. **console.log(Model.getDataSource().settings.name)** shows that the datasource has changed, however when I use the model and its datasource, it is still the previous one.

On ***datasources.local.js***, I have declared the datasources which I will be constantly attaching and detaching from my model `Model`.

```
// datasources.local.js

exports.datasource1 = {
  name: 'datasource1',
  connector: 'rest',
  ...
}

exports.datasource2 = {
  name: 'datasource2',
  connector: 'rest',
  ...
}
```

**So it seems that I cannot change the datasource to a datasource that has been used previously by the same model... I noticed that the problem is not switching to a new dataSource, but instead trying to attach a datasource that had been attached before by the same Model.**

Comment: did you achieve this if yes how please post sample code it will help me as well as other

Comment: Hi @bipin, unfortunately I couldn't make it work out...

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps the best choice would be to reload all models. Is it possible to happen in loopback?

Comment: I couldn't find anything on their docs about reloading models during execution.